# One Page Checkout extension infinite loading

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.2.4

Anyone having this problem with One Page Checkout Extension?

The onepage/ page doesn't stop loading (shows a "loading circle" in center of page). Using the Chrome Console, it shows the following error:

> checkout.js:805 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of
>   undefined

Circle in the middle of page:
[image: CIRCLE FROM HELL]

Comment: please tell your magento version and which checkout extension are you using?

Comment: Magento 1.9.2.4, extension: iwd checkout suite (this one: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-page-checkout.html)

Comment: I have implemented this extension in my many site but I have never face this issue. please check your browser console for error and try to solve that js error

Comment: The if that is returning error is this one: `if (typeof(response.payments) != "undefined") {
                $j_opc('#checkout-payment-method-load').html(response.payments);
                $j_opc('#checkout-payment-method-load').empty().html(response.payments).promise().done(function(){
                    IWD.OPC.BrainTree.init();
                });
                payment.initWhatIsCvvListeners();
                IWD.OPC.bindChangePaymentFields();
                IWD.OPC.Decorator.setCurrentPaymentActive();
            };` I'm using a specific payment method

Comment: I think there is no payment method active in your website for your current address if you are register user or maybe for guest user there is no payment method available ,please check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no payment method active in your website for your current address, if you are register user, or maybe for guest user there is no payment method available ,please check and let me know.

above two case is only possible case when this error come. Because you getting payment method null

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I think that this one page checkout just can't handle with the payment method that I choose :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

`extend.js` file connected to Magento theme in the old version. Replace `extend.js` on the actual version of the IWD OPC extension